# copy char array to char* in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, memcpy

I have a char array that I need to define in a function and return a char pointer, so i defined MAX which is the biggest size my char array can be according to my assigment and after I append part of it I want to copy it to char pointer so I can return it.
the size of the part of the array that is full is i and I did malloc to with this size, then I did memcpy to copy only the part I want(strcpy copied also the ampty fields), but it still put in my result more weird stuff, how do I get rid of this?

Code:

```
char* result = (char*)malloc(i*sizeof(char));

if (result == NULL)
    free(result);

memcpy(result, temp, i);

printf("%s", result);
return result;
```

Result of printf:

```
ccbcc²²²²U┤
```

while the result should be only "ccbcc".

Comment: If `i` is `strlen(temp)` then you allocate one too little (for the terminating null) and you copy one too little (that terminating null).

Comment: temp's size is 3000 but only i-1 fileds have values. the strlen comment return me 3000 and I dont want that..

Comment: If `temp` is a string, use `strcpy(result, temp)` instead of `memcpy` and make sure `i > strlen(temp)`. Also, do not cast the pointer returned by `malloc` in C programs.

Comment: `if (result == NULL) free(result);` FYI: [`free(NULL)` is a no-op](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3), maybe better: `if (result == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "malloc error\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: `char* result = (char*)malloc(i*sizeof(char));` allocates 1-byte of memory. The only string you can store there is the *empty-string* (single `'\0'` char -- not very useful)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it allocates `i` bytes of memory (assuming it is successful).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing like this: `printf("%s", result);`

you should be printing only indexes which are initialized and contains value:

```
for(int k=0;k<i;k++){
  printf("%c", s[k]);
}
```

Comment: I tried this one at the begining and it didnt work, but now suddenly it works! thanks:)

Comment: @Ran121 great !